# Power BI Authentication using REST API without GUI using Java (Refresh Token)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Currently I am getting Power BI Report from Power BI services with access token and embedding this report into IFrame using Azure AIDL Authentication.

Using this Java Library I am getting an JWT access token and fetching into my Power Bi report.

Below are the problems with this approach:

1) Access token has a short validity of 60 mins. and after that I fetch new access token using refresh token.

2) But the refresh token itself has a validity of 14 days and after that I need to manually log in and update the refresh token manually.

I want to avoid manual log in and wondering if there is any way to make this automatic.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I would look into using powerbi embedded, you do not need to use the users AD account to authenticate and view the report.  You would need to manage who sees what report however from your application, but fetching the report does not require user authentication with powerbi embedded.  You are given an access key in the azure portal. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-what-is-power-bi-embedded/

Comment: Yes agreed but that doesn't provide any security to the report. Hence I am embedding Azure Authentication token to visualize it in Web app.

Comment: What do you mean by manual log in? Are you looking for something like this: [Power BI API without GUI authentication redirect](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/How-to-use-Power-BI-Rest-API-without-GUI-authentication-redirect/m-p/14218#M119)?